# Do you need to run brew unlink / brew link before / after brew switch?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, homebrew

Do you need to run `brew unlink` / `brew link` before / after `brew switch`?

According to this link [https://docs.brew.sh/Tips-N'-Tricks#activate-a-previously-installed-version-of-a-formula](https://docs.brew.sh/Tips-N%27-Tricks#activate-a-previously-installed-version-of-a-formula) `brew switch` is activate a previously installed version of a formula.

Looks like I have some 'system' python installed(it's installed under `/usr/bin/python3`), that was not installed with brew, I can see it if I do `brew unlink python@3.9` and `brew unlink python@3.7`:

```
python -V
Python 3.7.3

/usr/bin/python3 -V
Python 3.7.3

which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Then I switch to python@3.9:

```
brew switch python@3.9 3.9.0_1
python -V
Python 3.9.0
```

Then I switch to python@3.7:

```
brew switch python@3.7 3.7.9
python -V
Python 3.9.0
```

but it still show me Python 3.9.0, `ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep python3` shows me python3.9 too.

I also tried to unlink all brew python packages before each brew switch test:

```
brew unlink python@3.7 && brew unlink python@3.9
brew switch python@3.7 3.7.9
python -V
Python 3.7.3


brew unlink python@3.7 && brew unlink python@3.9
brew switch python@3.9 3.9.0_1
python -V
Python 3.9.0
```

So seems for some reason it automatically links python@3.9 on brew switch and don't do it for python@3.7, why? Is `brew switch` have `brew unlink` / `brew link` inside it or should it be done manually?

Can I just do `brew unlink` / `brew link` to switch python version?

**Update:**

Seems newer versions of `brew` don't have `switch`:

```
Error: Calling `brew switch` is disabled! Use `brew link` @-versioned formulae instead.

brew --version
Homebrew 2.7.7
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 918f0; last commit 2021-02-04)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 2b83c; last commit 2021-02-04)
```

So now it should be something like this:

```
brew unlink python@3.7 && brew unlink python@3.9
brew link python@3.7
python -V
Python 3.7.9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`brew switch` is no more a brew command.

```
$ brew --version                                                                    
Homebrew 3.0.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 8d644; last commit 2021-02-10)

$ brew switch mariadb@10.3                                                  
Error: Unknown command: switch
```

The [Tips and Tricks](https://docs.brew.sh/Tips-N%27-Tricks#activate-a-previously-installed-version-of-a-formula) page you were referring to in your question also remove any mention of `brew switch`.

> **Installing previous versions of formulae**
>
> The supported method of installing specific versions of some formulae
> is to see if there is a versioned formula (e.g. gcc@7) available. If
> the version you’re looking for isn’t available, consider using brew
> extract.

Either, no mention of `brew switch` in `man brew`.

So it seems that your question has been solved upstream by Homebrew maintainers.

Note that `brew switch` was deprecated since [Homebrew 2.6.0](https://brew.sh/2020/12/01/homebrew-2.6.0/) .

== Update ==

If we take your example with python@3.7 and python@3.9. We should first inspect the output of `brew info python@3.7` and `brew info python@3.9`. We see that python@3.7 is [keg-only](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#what-does-keg-only-mean):

```
python@3.7 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.
```

which is not the case of python@3.9 because it is for now an alias of the python formula. This means that installing python@3.9 automatically run `brew link python@3.9` and installing python@3.7 does not run `brew link python@3.7`.

Then to list which files will be linked with python@3.9, you can run `brew link --dry-run python@3.9`

```
Would link:
/usr/local/bin/2to3
/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.9
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.9
/usr/local/bin/idle3
/usr/local/bin/idle3.9
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3.9
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.9
/usr/local/bin/python3.9-config
/usr/local/bin/wheel3
/usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.9.1
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.9-embed.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.9.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python3-embed.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
```

To list which files will be linked with python@3.7, run `brew link --dry-run python@3.7`:

```
Would link:
/usr/local/bin/2to3
/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.7
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.7
/usr/local/bin/idle3
/usr/local/bin/idle3.7
/usr/local/bin/pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3.7
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3
/usr/local/bin/pydoc3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7-config
/usr/local/bin/python3.7m
/usr/local/bin/python3.7m-config
/usr/local/bin/pyvenv
/usr/local/bin/pyvenv-3.7
/usr/local/bin/wheel3
/usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.1
/usr/local/share/man/man1/python3.7.1
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.7.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.7m.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Python
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Resources
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7
/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current
```

So to answer your question, one way to switch between python@3.7 and python@3.9 is by using `brew link` and `brew unlink` and yes this can break things if you have scripts which are compatible with python@3.7 and not with python@3.9 or vice versa.

There is another way to use different version of python in the same time. This is explained at the end of the output of `brew link --dry-run python@3.7`:

```
If you need to have this software first in your PATH instead consider running:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

For scripts that neeeds python@3.7, you can set:

```
 export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin
```

and for scripts that neeeds python@3.9, you can set:

```
 export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So which way is now a proper way to 'switch' between python versions? If I do `unlink` / `link` can it break things? i.e. if I 'switch' to `python@3.7`, but some other formula 'depends' on `python@3.9`?